# (RESOLVIDO) Cordova exibir só o ID do Cliente após logado em Ajax

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo um app com o cordova, está rodando, porém quando entro na sessão de pedidos, exibe a lista toda de pedido quero só do cliente uso  (a clausula `WHERE`) embora não tenha inserido  `cliente_Id`, assim;

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","root") or die("connection error");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login']))

    {
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $cliente_email= $_POST['cliente_email'];

    $cliente_senha= $_POST['cliente_senha'];

       $login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE `cliente_senha`='$cliente_senha' AND `cliente_email`='$cliente_email' AND
 `username`='$username'"));

              if($login != 0){

         echo "ok";

               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

             }else{

            echo "error";
          }

        }

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Exibe a lista:

```
$data=array();

$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dados_clientes` ORDER BY 
`dados_clientes`.`id`  DESC LIMIT 1");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){

 $data[]=$row;

}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Aqui mesmo peguei algumas dicas utilizando session lado servidor e cliente, beleza uso no login, entro tranquilamente com `sessionStorage`, agora sendo que do lado do servidor também tem que utilizar `$_SESSION`, mas a maioria das dicas o `Start()` são em paginas php o que não é o caso em html, como startar esta `$_SESSION` php do lado do cliente, como se conversam via ajax estas sessions. Se puderem apontar um caminho, o restante será fácil.

```
<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url = "auth.php";

        $("#loginButton").click(function(){


    var username=$("#username").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();

    var dataString =

    "&username="  +username+
    "&password=" +password +

    "&login=";

    if(

        $.trim(username).length>0 & 
        $.trim(password).length>0

        )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connectando...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="sucesso")
                {
                    localStorage.login="true";
                    localStorage.username=username;
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
                else if(data="falha")
                {
                    alert("Login errado");
                    $("#login").html('Login..');
                }
            }
        });
    }return false;

});

});
</script>

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

$login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE 
 `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"));
    if($login != 0){
        echo "success";
    }else{

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);
        if(is_array($row) && !empty($row)) {

        $validuser = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['valid'] = $validuser;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username or password.";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='login.php'>Go back</a>";
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid'])) {
       echo "success";         
     }
   }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Bem de qualquer forma aqui está minha estrutura atual,

E abaixo a tabela relacionada.

```
<?php 
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","root") or die("connection 
error");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

 session_start(); 

 if(!isset($_SESSION['valid'])) {

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
  $name    =  $_POST['name'];
  $qty     =   $_POST['qty'];
   $price   = $_POST['price'];
  $loginId = $_SESSION['id'];
  // checking empty fields
  if(empty($name) || empty($qty) || empty($price)) {
    if(empty($name)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($qty)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Quantity field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($price)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Price field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else { 

 $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products (`name`, `qty`, `price`, `login_id`) VALUES ('$name','$qty','$price', '$loginId')");

    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='view.php'>View Result</a>";
   }
  }

  }
  ?>
```

Database Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`qty` int(5) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
CONSTRAINT FK_products_1
FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES login(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Olá pessoal, depois de varias buscas continuo na mesma, então resolvi editar um vídeo para deixar mais clara minha situação, vocês podem ver aqui 
[explica][1]
[1]:

O exemplo é básico e idêntico ao projeto original. Sim pessoal uma coisa que esqueci de mostrar no video foi se caso eu agregasse as tabelas aí sim a tabela 'course_details' funcionaria ela insere os dados normalmente. mas não tem sentido.

Comment: Quando logar, você tem que pegar o ID do cliente e salvar em sessionStorage ou localStorage. Depois, cada requisição ajax você usará o id desse cliente.
No PHP, a consulta aos dados do cliente está errada.

Comment: Coloque também a sua estrutura de banco de dados, senão fica difícil saber como montar a query.

Comment: Certo inicialmente quero pedir desculpas por talvez, ter violado alguma regra do stack atualizando o código, quanto as dicas, como o ID? pode me ajudar na consulta? eu desenvolvi um site teste e deu certo mas quando passei para ajax, não funfa.

Comment: Não infrigiu as regras, apenas não fez uma pergunta concreta. Preciso da sua estrutura do banco de dados, primeiramente.

Comment: Ok meu caro Gui como o ID? ou seja como apontar pro id cliente na session ou local storage, como fazer e, a consulta acredito ter corrigido, explicando que eu tenho uma tabela PEDIDOS _fk  relacionada e é esta tabela que preciso apontar para "1" cliente, pois mostra tudo que ela tem, quando listo e preciso só de uma info

Comment: Meu caro Guilherme desculpe a demora fiquei por um tempo isolado, e por isso a demora acrescentei a estrutura como solicitou...Um abraço

Comment: Na sua requisição de login, alem de salvar o username, salvar também o ID do usuário. Com esse ID, você irá criar uma consulta no seu PHP usando o WHERE do ID do usuário.

Comment: Opa meu caro, então já fiz, inclusive consigo logar e reconhecer a session do usuário, só que no VIEW não lista  e não insere na tabela"products" , aí fiz um teste com as tabelas sem estar relacionadas, pois bem, acaba que cadastra normalmente o trecho alterado `$q=$con->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE login_id=".$_SESSION['id']." "); `                                                     a conclusão que cheguei foi que ao estarem relacionadas FK "products" não funfa após logado, terei que recorrer a uma outra estratégia e entender o porque. Valeu pela atenção. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Olá pessoal o código está correto? alguem testou, para ver se esqueci alguma coisa?

Comment: Olá pessoa, encontrei a falha, as tabela relacionadas não funcionam em AJAX, só se for em PHP puro, alguém conhece algum método de tabelas relacionais que utilize Ajax. To pesquisando até hoje e nada encontro, meu projeto esta rodando de modo manual, ta dificil. valeu!!

Comment: Olha, as tabelas relacionais funcionam sim sia ajax, mas enviando para um backend em PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Pessoal resolvido por incrível que pareça o erro foi quando atualizei este código e o erro estava nesta linha`$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products....` insistindo num erro grosseiro como `$result =mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,...` dai então corrigi....Portanto a requisição Ajax valida de fato os dados relacionais... Com uma ressalva,..se for relacionar mais que cinco tabela execute direto no mysql workbench....Valeu galera.